# Can "should" be used to mean "if" and used to mean "would" in the same sentence?

Tags: should, would, conditionals

It's grammatical to use "should" like "if":

> - Should you need me, call.
> - I'll be available should she ask for me.
> - Should my mother call, let her know I'll be back shortly.

It's also grammatical to use "should" for "would":

> - If you call me, I should hope that I answer.
> - When I ask you a question, I should expect that you not lie to me.
> - Were you not to seize this opportunity, I should think you mad.

HOWEVER, is it grammatical to use both of these grammatical conventions at the same time?  In a conditional sentence, can "should" be used in both the protasis and the apodosis?

Examples:

> - Should you desire to go, I should hope you do. (If you desire to go, I would hope you do.)
> - Should he come, I should like to meet him. (If he comes, I'd like to    meet him.)
> - We should expect a call from you should there be any problem. (We would expect a call from you if there's any problem.)

Comment: They all sound rather dated and effected, with sentence 3 sounding the most "modern".  I don't see any reason why they are not grammatical. But I'd replace the the "*should* hope you do" with "would" for reasons of clarity. Let's see what someone else says, I'll be just as interested to hear their thoughts.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : I should be devastated should no one else answer.

Comment: What would you do should this question be found duplicate? +1)

Comment: @Rathony : I should be quite surprised, for I checked thoroughly.

Comment: I should be punished.

Comment: @Rathony : Have you been naughty, naughty, Rathony?  I should hope so.

Comment: Should you use should to mean "if" and should to mean "would" in the same sentence, I should hope that you not do so within earshot of me.

Comment: @Dan Romik : Should I so choose, I *should*... or *shall*... or *will*...  Hmm, I should hope that it's one of those three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to use two *should*s in the same conditional:

> Should anyone phone asking when the drilling's going to stop, I should imagine we'll all be finished by 2 o'clock.

Of course, it's not strictly accurate to think that the first *should*  here is replacing *if*. Here's the same sentence with *if* reinserted:

> If anyone should phone asking when the drilling's going to stop, I should imagine we'll all be finished by 2 o'clock.

Here we can see both  *if* and *should* together in the same protasis. The first sentence uses subject-auxiliary inversion to mark the conditional protasis. The *if* has been dropped and the Subject, *anyone* and the auxiliary verb *should*  have changed places.

Comment: Much like saying, "Were anyone to phone," the inversion negates the "if."  (If anyone were to phone)

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Exactly so.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it is not.

The first trio of sentences is fine.

There's a problem with the second haiku:

> If you call me, I should hope that I answer.

I don't know what this means. It sounds needlessly paranoid.

> When I ask you a question, I should expect that you not lie to me.

Doesn't make much sense in American English. Some Brits would find it kind of awkward too.

> Were you not to seize this opportunity, I should think you mad.

In British English, maybe. Does sound a bit strained, though.

The third group is a total mess. Probably because ... uh ... what did you call it? ... the protasis ... and what's-that-other-one-called ... should not ... ha, ha ... should not be the same word? Yeah, that's gotta be it.